# Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG while running on ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, class, ubuntu, testng, classpath

I am able to run the XML file from the eclipse but when I run the XML file from ubuntu terminal i am getting this error I tried the solution but not able to solve this problem

the command which I am using on Ubuntu

```
java -cp /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/bin:/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: i have added all jar files including testng6.9.9.jar

Comment: Try `...ce/seffcon/libs/* org.testng...` (notice the slash before the star)

Comment: thank command is running but the test case is getting failed and when i run the same command on eclipse the test case is getting passed